# Why does Travis-CI bomb with ruby 1.9.3 but not 1.9.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, travis-ci

Check out the different test runs...what am I doing wrong here?  When using ruby 1.9.3, my test suite runs to completion without error but something after is blowing up.  Something about test/unit but I'm not even including test/unit in my rails app.  I appreciate any help!

http://travis-ci.org/#!/leesmith/decent_authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace gem `shoulda` with `shoulda-matchers` if you're using rspec instead of test::unit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work on your googling skills ;)

Try adding a `:require => false` to shoulda in your Gemfile:

```
gem "shoulda", :require => false
```

From [this discussion](https://gist.github.com/1549790).